# GraphQL readiness for .net development

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-web-api, graphql

I found GraphQL as an enticing option to decouple front-end development from APIs (potentially a great fit for our company, which does lots of API customization for each customer). However, I can't quite work out if it's ready for a .NET development environment, or whether it's still considered an early technology? I also can't tell if it has bigger problems under the covers (e.g. N+1 issue). Any experience and guidance for GraphQL with a .NET implementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fact that there is no answer here after one month should tell it's tale.

I have shifted my focus from .NET Framework to .NET Core and after trying out the .NET libraries available, I soon went for an API gateway built on TypeScript and the more mature Facebook supported GraphQL implementation.

With the server issue solved, my combined .NET Framework/Core based client easily communicates with the API gateway. As the gateway itself is rather lightweight, exchanging this for a more solid .NET Core implementation later will be easy.

Answer (score 3):

It's now 2019, I stumbled upon this question and I thought I'd share this cool GraphQL library for .NET

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet

Don't forget to `dotnet add package GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground` to get the very sweet ui playground:
[image]

Comment: The library was available also in 2016 when my answer was made, but has matured a lot since then. Thanks for pointing this out!